# Can i use jquery for onKeyUp on multiple elements?

Tags: jquery

i have a bunch of text fields that i want to run a function when onkeyup is done. They will all run the same function so is there a way i can just do that on one line instead of this:

```
$('#element1').keyup(function(){getData()});
$('#element2').keyup(function(){getData()});
```

Also, if i can do that, how can i throw and onchange in there for a dropdown? Thanks all!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use commas to separate elements:

```
$("#element1, #element2").keyup(getData);
```

But how about using classes instead of listing all IDs:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input id="element1" class="element" />
<input id="element2" class="element" />

// JavaScript
$(".element").keyup(getData);
```

Comment: that makes sense. how would i throw an onchange in there for the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, using classes is a good solution. How about that: `$(":text.element").keyup(getData)` and `$("select.element").change(getData)`?

Answer (score 6):

Either you append them in your selector:

```
$('#element1, #element2').keyup(function(){ // ...
```

or you use `add()` which in this case will probably be more efficient, as jQuery can use a shortcut for ID-only selectors using `getElementById`:

```
$('#element1').add('#element2').keyup(function(){ // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to use multiple selectors within `$()`.

```
$('#element1, #element2').keyup(function(){
   getData()
 });
```

or in short

```
$('#element1, #element2').keyup(getData);
```

If you want to bind `.change()` event to you multiple `select` box then give all `select` a common class

```
<select class="myselect"></select>
<select class="myselect"></select>
<select class="myselect"></select>

$('.myselect').on('change', function() {

});
```

Comment: your second example is functionally not the same as the first did you mean .keyup(getData)?

Comment: Confused... so can i do
`$('#element1, #element2').keyup(getData);
or not?

Comment: @Damien you can do `$('#element1, #element2').keyup(getData);`.